# Headers for `nuxt-axios` custom plugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I create a custom axios plugin extending `$axios` to add headers to all request which use `$customAxios` but not `$axios`.

Is not working fine because don't matter if i use `$axios` or `$customAxios` both returns this headers.

`plugins/customAxios.js`

```
export default ({ $axios }, inject) => {
    $axios.onRequest(config => {
        config.headers.common.Authorization = 'token';
        config.headers.common["Custom-header"] = 'blabla;
    });

  inject("customAxios", $axios);
};
```

What should i do to fix this?